# How to create windows pendrive manually on Debian?

Tags: linux, usb, debian, usb-flash-drive

I want to create a Windows pendrive manually to improve my project. I used following commands to create:

```
sudo wipefs --all /dev/sdb
sudo parted --script /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
sudo parted mkpart primary ntfs 4MB 8000MB
sudo mkfs.ntfs --quick /dev/sdb1
sudo parted --script /dev/sdb set 1 boot on
sudo mount windows7.iso /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media
sudo cp -r /mnt/* /media
sudo umount /mnt
sudo umount /media
```

Then I turned of fast boot and secure boot options from BIOS and tried to boot from flash. But it didn't work. Can you explain why? And How can I create it? Note: without woeusb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing parts depend on which boot mode you intend to use.

#### Legacy BIOS mode

The BIOS doesn't know about bootable partitions by itself – it only does one thing: load the boot sector from the MBR and run it. It's the job of the disk's own boot sector to look for a bootable partition.

To make that work, you should write a Windows MBR to the disk using `ms-sys`:

```
ms-sys --mbr7 /dev/sdb
```

(The Syslinux MBR might also work as an alternative, since it does the same thing: read the partition table and jump to the first bootable partition.)

Next, once the MBR first-stage bootloader has found your bootable partition, *that partition* needs to have its own boot sector as well (the VBR), which will know how to find the bootable files (specifically BOOTMGR). I'm not entirely sure if mkfs.ntfs writes a proper one, but ms-sys can do it as well:

```
ms-sys --ntfs /dev/sdb1
```

#### UEFI mode

UEFI doesn't use boot sectors and doesn't search for the "bootable" flag, so there's no point in setting it. Instead, the firmware directly searches for partitions which contain a recognizable filesystem.

Most UEFI systems only support FAT and do not understand NTFS. There are workarounds for this (e.g. UEFI:NTFS that comes with Rufus), but you still need to start with a FAT32 partition – so might as well use it for everything.

```
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdb1
```

If you were doing this with Windows 10, you would run into a problem of the `install.wim` file being too large for FAT32. This can be solved using `wimsplit` to generate partial .swm files, but it probably won't be an issue with Windows 7 anyway.

Comment: It worked !. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is create a single NTFS partition on a USB drive, copied all the files from a Windows 7 ISO to it, and tried to boot it.  As you've found, that doesn't work.  Here's a couple of reasons:

- If you're using UEFI, which most modern computers are, the firmware will only understand a few types of file systems.  FAT is required, and usually ISO9660 or UDF are supported as well for booting off of optical media.  NTFS is much more complex and usually isn't supported, so putting all the files on an NTFS file system isn't going to make it bootable.
- In addition, UEFI does not support DOS (MBR) partition tables.  You need to use a GPT partition table, and the bootable area must have a certain partition type (EFI System Partition) in order to be bootable.  If you lack one, it won't be bootable.
- If you're using BIOS, then often your bootloader needs to know where on the disk your data is in order to properly boot it.  Those offsets will have changed, so that won't work there either.  You'll need to run some sort of bootloader to make it bootable.

[This article explains how to do it](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/), which sounds like you need to just use a FAT file system isntead of an NTFS file system, and that the partition table needs to be GPT with the correct partition type.  However, it's for Windows 10, so that may or may not apply to Windows 7 ISOs.  Since Windows 7 is not receiving security updates, there's no reason to install it, though.

Comment: The base UEFI specification does fully support MBR partition tables (and defines the "EFI System Partition" type IDs for both GPT and MBR), and most UEFI-bootable removable disks indeed use MBR partitioning. Removable disks are also not required to have the correct partition type ID, instead booting the first FAT partition (and IIRC the requirement is a bit flexible even for fixed disks).

Comment: That assumes that the firmware handles removable media properly, which it does not always.  As any Linux kernel developer can tell you, firmware is terrible.

Comment: Well, I think that's a reasonable assumption. Yes, there are non-spec-compliant firmwares, but "non-spec-compliant" is the key word here -- they don't define UEFI... _(I mean, for example, there are also UEFI firmwares that only support booting Microsoft\Bootmgfw.efi no matter what path was set, but that doesn't generalize into "UEFI does not support booting GRUB".)_ But in practice, even Microsoft's official "Win10 Media Creation Tool" builds MBR-partitioned USB sticks for UEFI installation, so I assume they consider it a safe choice.